# Angular accordion: animate toggle

Tags: angularjs

Can someone advice how to do `accordion` that `toggles` with animation and if I click on 1st div, only the 1st panel will show?
http://plnkr.co/edit/LdBVT0zbYdshITwr3qjh?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  <body ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">
      <div class="accordion" ng-click="show=show==true? false:true;">
        {{item.id}}
      </div>
      <div class="repeated-item" ng-model="accordionContent" ng-show="show">
        {{item.name}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

You don't need controller for this purpose, it can be handled directly using directives
[Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/ELHw35EjqFdN5tMXgMwV?p=preview)

Comment: Can you add animation when the 2nd div is shown? Tried to add css but it didn't help me.

Comment: There is no animation in Plunker demo. It is just showing or hiding

Answer (score 0):

Instead of re-inventing the wheel, use [ui bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap)'s [accordion](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/accordion) directive. It comes with a lot of options for customization.

```js
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('AccordionDemoCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.oneAtATime = true;
  $scope.isFirstOpen = true;
});
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.3.3.js"></script>
<script src="example.js"></script>

<div ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo" ng-controller="AccordionDemoCtrl">
  <uib-accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
    <uib-accordion-group heading="Static Header, initially expanded" is-open="isFirstOpen">
      This content is straight in the template.
    </uib-accordion-group>
    <uib-accordion-group heading="Another Static Header">
      This content is straight in the template.
    </uib-accordion-group>
  </uib-accordion>
</div>
```

[official plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/5KtOpnqD6PiqAgRMWTit?p=preview)

Comment: Sorry, but I have too many angular plugins that conflicts with others. So I can't use ui bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

Here is  a solution for your problem in gennerally when you working with ng-repeat you could manipualte in your fucntions $index value of your arrray

[http://plnkr.co/edit/gBJPcFNIgUTWo5gdZzUb?p=preview`][1]

//JS

```
$scope.toggle = function($index) {
  $scope.index = $index;
};
```

//AND IN HTML SIMPLE TOGGLE CLASS

```
  <div class="repeated-item" data-ng-class="{'open-accordion' : index === $index}" ng-model="accordionContent" >
```